# npm install hangs on specific package only (ts-jest)

Tags: typescript, npm, ts-jest

[image]

I am just trying to install `ts-jest` on new project like:

```bash
$ mkdir test && cd test
$ npm init -y
$ npm install ts-jest
```

All other packages can be installed with no error or hanging but only `ts-jest` never be installed and keep stuck at `sill idealTree buildDeps`

If I try to install from github directly it allows me to install package

```bash
$ npm install git+https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest.git
```

**Here's what I have tried:**

1. Remove package-lock and node_modules
2. Reinstall node
3. Change node version (16, 17, 18, etc...)
4. Restart Mac (M1)
5. Set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
6. ssh-add
7. Install another version of tsjest (v29.0.5, v26.5.3, v25 ...)
8. Test on another mac (Intel)
9. Test on another Wifi
10. Test on LAN

But none of them did work for me.

**Current Environment:**

- Mac M1 Ventura 13.0
- Node v16.13.2
- Npm 9.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I can recommend is to check your SSH settings with GitHub.

I searched around and the people who have similar 'get stuck' issues have resolved it by setting up the SSH key right.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17228

---

To set up your SSH key

https://dev.to/brandonwie/how-do-i-connect-2-different-github-account-1b60

The post is about dual set up, but you'll get the idea.

And make sure you add the SSH key to your GitHub

Comment: There are other possible tryouts in the link above. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've already tried the solutions from that links and none of them worked for me :(

Comment: @user8659363 hope you figure it out. let me know if anything works.

Comment: I found it was a korean internet carrier problem from this github issue https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/3992. everything is ok now. Thanks for your answer!